# Microsoft Graph Api: download information file and stream in a single call

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Is it possible to do?

Currently, I need two different calls:

File information call:

```
var driveItem = _graphClient
    .Drives["<my_drive_id>"]
    .Items["<my_file_id>"]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync()
    .Result;
```

File stream call:

```
var file = _graphClient
    .Drives["<my_drive_id>"]
    .Items["<my_file_id>"]
    .Content
    .Request()
    .GetAsync()
    .Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. Your first call returns a JSON response, the second returns a file stream response. You cannot return two different content types in a single HTTP response.

Comment: I know that my two calls are different. I asked if there is a method to get both file information and stream in a single call instead of making two.

Comment: As stated, this isn't possible. It cannot return both a Stream and JSON in a single response.